# A Sandbox Migration Bot

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, sandbox

I outlined [a question in the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13003/69054) for a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) to create a user script that can migrate challenges to and from the Sandbox. I've since been informed by multiple people that the criteria I outlined were not feasible for a userscript.

One point of discussion from @FryAmTheEggman is that:

> Automating this wouldn't really help at all, since the sandbox only does anything if the poster wants to use it.

Here are some reasons I think such a tool would be helpful:

- Most new users are unaware of the Sandbox, and they are (usually) the ones posting poorly written questions
- I think it will help us retain more new users, because the negative connotations of downvotes and closings are mitigated by constructive criticism on the Sandbox post
- I think that moving questions to and from the Sandbox is a somewhat tedious *but* mechanical problem, which means it is well-suited for being automated
- This also helps users on mobile devices, for whom it is even more difficult and tedious to copy and paste the raw Markdown and make all the edits and comments

#### So, here are my questions:

#### 1. Do we want a Sandbox migration bot?

#### 2. If we do, how should we go about creating it?

Specifically, should it be:

- A challenge like [the one I have outlined](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13003/69054),
- A community effort in some other form, or
- Something for someone to create on their own?

Comment: How do you suggest that this be done? The Stack Exchange software does not allow "migrating" a question to an answer or vice versa.

Comment: @Doorknob If the author themselves activates the bot, can it post as them? In that case, it could be as simple as clicking a link to move the challenge from one location to the other. I'm not sure what is and isn't possible because I've never done this before

Comment: You certainly can't take actions under another user's credentials simply by having them click a link - that would be a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: Other apps have abilities like "Allow this app to post as you on Facebook", at which point you authorize or deny this permission. Does SE have anything like this?

Comment: Stack Exchange does implement OAuth, but at that point if the user isn't willing to copy/paste into the sandbox, it's unlikely that this would change that.

Answer (score 5):

## This doesn't seem useful

Copying a challenge between the sandbox and main site is a simple matter of copying-and-pasting the body, title, and tags. Three copy-and-pastes really isn't a large amount of effort, and is trivial in comparison with basically anything else you might want to do with respect to a challenge or Sandbox post. (Sometimes I change headings between level 1 and level 2, but that's basically just a nicety rather than something that's necessary.)

Additionally, it's quite common for me to make minor changes to a post (typically to the title or introduction) while moving it between the main site and sandbox; an automated process wouldn't do that at all. We'd have to institute a culture of Sandbox posts being *identical* to the desired challenge on Main (which is not the case at the moment), and I think that'd be detrimental to the usability of the Sandbox.